# iPhone 3G on OS 3.0

Tags: iphone, upgrade

I have an iPhone 3G & since I have upgraded to OS 3.0 it has really started to slow down. All the applications are slow, typing is slow & moreover the games I purchased previously run too slow.

I searched the internet I did find people complaining but nobody had a solution.

I did a fresh install of the OS but the problem still persists.

Is it because of the numerous applications I have installed? OS 2.2.1 worked flawlessly, all the applications ran fine

I even had battery problems when I first upgraded, then I did a clean install battery problems went away but still the speed sucks.

What should I do, sue Apple?

Comment: Is your phone jailbroken?

Comment: yes it is 

this problem related to jailbreak ..?

because ive seen other forms where people without jailbreaking are having the same problem ....

but they werent able to troubleshoot it

Answer (score 1):

It's not because of all the apps you have installed.  Several of the fixes with the 3.0 OS update are not effective unless you reset all your preferences.  I avoided doing this for a long time but finally did it and it really helped my wifi connectivity among other things:

From [apple.com](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1737):  Reset iPhone settings. From the Home screen choose Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings. All your preferences are reset, but no data or media is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

you might have done this already.. but just to reconfirm..

you would need to do a fresh install.. not an upgrade or restore of the prev backup.. as some of the internals of the OS have changed in the major upgrade from ver. 2.x to 3.x the old settings do mess up..

Do a clean install and sync all your apps again with iTunes and im sure you would like the new OS much better..

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that as my iPhone gets closer to full data capacity, it seems to get much slower too.  Once I freed up more space by removing some video podcasts and putting a few less songs on it, it started "getting slow" less often.